# Why my alertdialog for OK button still can be click, I already added if else statement for login still can click button OK if no account at database?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

MY PROBLEMS :

> **1. I have error on Background.java**
>   [image]
>
> **2. I already use if else if statement for alertdialog.**
>
> **3. I want when I click OK at alertdialog, it will check account on database, if the account exist on database, it will go to the next page. If dont have the account on database, it will stay at the login page.**
>
> **4. Correct me if i am wrong when doing if else if statement for alertdialog OK button.**

Below are my java coding :

**Background.java**

```
public class Background extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Activity activity;

Background(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://172.20.10.4/LoginLab3.php";
    String reg_url = "http://172.20.10.4/RegisterLab3.php";
    if (type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(type.equals("register"))
    {
        try {
            String name = params[1];
            String surname = params[2];
            String age = params[3];
            String username = params[4];
            String password = params[5];
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("surname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(surname,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Welcome.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) context).finish();
            } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) context).finish();
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    dialog.create().show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText username, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    password = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

public void OnLog(View view)
{
    String Username = username.getText().toString();
    String Password = password.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";

    if(Username.equals("") || Password.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill the Username and Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {

        Background bg = new Background(this);
        bg.execute(type, Username, Password);
    }
}

public void OnReg(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class));
}
}
```

**Help me! **

Comment: Why are you only handling `"true"` and `"false"` in the `onClick` function? What about when `doInBackground` returns `null`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How to change it?